how to achieve seamless UVs of multple meshes?
I am trying to do a project in three.js where I require adjacent/overlapping meshes in my model to have UVs in such a way so that when a texture(img as texture) is applied it will look seamless across multiple meshes.
A crude example 
when i try to unwrap the meshes (1,2,3). I find it impossible for them to have a proportional UVs so as to achieve seamless nature.

when I try to rearrange one tile's edge(dotted line)in UV editor, all the other gets messed up.
I want to achieve UVs such that the colored tiles look seamless across Mesh 1,2 and 3. Joining all three meshes is not an option due to project constraints in threejs. How do I do it?

It defeats the whole point of UV maps : to separate parts of the mesh into separated islands. In your example, you may be able to align all 3 surfaces (I'm not even sure) but for a whole object, you can't have seemless mapping. What is the motivation to have the 3 surfaces aligned perfectly ?

shoe customization project in three.js. There are two reasons why I want three separate islands to be aligned perfectly 1) islands must be separate so the user can assign colors to independent mesh/islands 2) UV must be aligned so when user uploads an image to side of the shoe, the image looks seamless across multiple island! (generally drawings overlap three adjacent meshes) https://www.reddit.com/r/OnePiece/comments/jsr63y/would_you_like_to_wear_a_pair_of_custom_made/ - something like this

Then you probably want to U > Project from View, no ?

oh thats a perfect solution! however what if the adjacent meshes aren't facing the same side (view)? ex : https://ibb.co/Dr8fy2w. 1,2,3,4 islands are facing different sides(1 and 2 are completely opposite) and i want to place image overlapping all three meshes?

Then have multiple UV maps with multiple Project from View. For example one for the side image, one for the back logo, etc...
